# Specifing environment in chef

Tags: chef-infra

I have a java application for which the spring attribute is passed via the environment attribute as below.

```
name "dev"
description "The test environment"
    override_attributes({"dspring" => {"active_profile" => "dev",
                                       "jss_cert_location" => "/opt/mount1/certs/jssecacerts"},
```

I am looking for similar approach to define the environment for a ruby app in chef. The command used to execute this app is:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /opt/mount2/ozz/current/src/main.py --port=8080 --debug --log_file_prefix=/opt/mount2/ozz/logs/ozz.log --log_file_max_size=1000000 --env=test
```

How do i define this "--env" parameter in each chef environment (dev, test,stage & prod)?

Below is an extract from the recipe:

```
ark 'python' do
  url 'https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.8/Python-2.7.8.tgz'
  path "/opt/mount1/"
  owner 'python'
  action :put
end

execute "cd #{node[:base_dir]}/python && ./configure && make && make altinstall" do
  not_if { File.exists?('/usr/local/bin/python2.7') }
end

remote_file "#{node[:base_dir]}/get-pip.py" do
  source "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py"
  mode 00755
  not_if { File.exists?("#{node[:base_dir]}/get-pip.py")}
end

execute "/usr/local/bin/python2.7 #{node[:base_dir]}/get-pip.py"

cookbook_file "ua-parser-master.tar" do
  path "/tmp/ua-parser-master.tar"
  not_if { File.exists?('/tmp/ua-parser-master.tar') }
end

execute 'tar -C /tmp -xvf /tmp/ua-parser-master.tar && chown -R root.root /tmp/ua-parser-master/ && /usr/local/bin/pip install /tmp/ua-parser-master'

execute '/usr/local/bin/pip install tornado pyyaml user-agents'

template "/etc/init.d/#{node[:application_name]}" do
  source 'python_init'
  mode 00755
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  variables(
    :application_name => node[:application_name],
  )
end

deploy_revision "/opt/mount1/#{node[:application_name]}" do
  repo "#{node[:application_repo]}"
  user "python"
  keep_releases 10
  action :deploy
  migrate false
  symlink_before_migrate.clear
  create_dirs_before_symlink
  purge_before_symlink.clear
  symlinks.clear
  symlinks {}
  notifies :restart, "service[#{node[:application_name]}]"
end

service "#{node[:application_name]}" do
  supports :restart => true
  action :enable
end
```

Comment: Can you share code for your recipe that's responsible for running/setup your ruby app? (btw you mentioned ruby app, but in example it seems that is python app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the chef environment match the parameter you wish to pass and that the command is inside this template:

```
template "/etc/init.d/#{node[:application_name]}" do
  source 'python_init'
  mode 00755
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  variables(
    :application_name => node[:application_name],
  )
end
```

The `python_init` template line for the execution can be written:

```
/usr/local/bin/python2.7 /opt/mount2/ozz/current/src/main.py --port=8080 --debug --log_file_prefix=/opt/mount2/ozz/logs/ozz.log --log_file_max_size=1000000 --env=<%= node.chef_environment %>
```

Templates in chef use erb to render the final file.

- `<%= variable %>` is the placeholder in erb
- `node.chef_environment` is a method to the Chef node object which give the environment name of the node.